# Passing data between custom view and view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uicontrol

I've got a custom UIControl (TestControl) and want to pass a simple string to a label on the main view. The UIControl (TestControl) sits inside a UIView (CustomView) which has been placed on the storyboard using a view which has got the custom class (CustomView).

What would be a simple implementation that would take care of that?

I noticed that the CustomView is called before the viewDidLoad() in the ViewController.

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

@IBOutlet var someLabel: UILabel!

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

TestControl.swift

```
import UIKit

class TestControl: UIControl {

    // Initializer
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    //this is where it would be good if a string could be passed to a label

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

CustomView.swift

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class CustomView: UIView{

    #if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
    override func willMoveToSuperview(newSuperview: UIView?) {

      let testing: TestControl = TestControl(frame: self.bounds)
      self.addSubview(testing)

    }

    #else
    override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()

        let testing: TestControl = TestControl(frame: self.bounds)
        self.addSubview(testing)

    }
    #endif
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a control in a storyboard, all you should have to do is to hook up the the `didChange` event handler to an `IBAction` in your view controller. This can then interpret this action to do what you want.

Comment: Would that be possible given the above example? If so, how?

Comment: I don't see your control's implementation of  `sendActionsForControlEvents:`